# Mysql query fails to order time correctly, polymer 1.0 dom-repeat issues

Tags: php, mysql, polymer

Sorry for the mundane question but i've tryed this for a little while now and cannot come to the conclusion on the problem.

I simply and retrieving rows from a certain day and am trying to order them by the same column. but they do not seem to order correctly. Heres my query

```
 SELECT * FROM property_card_bookings 
 WHERE property_card_bookings_worker = '{$userid}' 
 AND DATE(property_card_bookings_starttime) = '{$day}' 
 ORDER BY TIME(property_card_bookings_starttime)
```

As these are bookings i want to list them by earliest start time. But nothing i try seems to work. Heres what im getting:

[image]

Image from console of returned ajax data
[image]

it runs iron-ajax once i set the params

```
        <!-- Ajax call to retrieve the data once params is set -->
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{params}}">
            <iron-ajax
                auto
                method="GET"
                url="../api/bookings/"
                params='{{params}}'
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="handleResponse"
                last-response="{{data}}">
            </iron-ajax>
        </template>

                // In polymer function
                this.params = {
                    type: 'dayBookings',
                    userId: this.userId,
                    date: getJustDate(this.rawDate)
                };
```

Seems to be arranging them by the id

[image: Works in mySql... fml]

Comment: How is the `time` being stored?  My guess is that it is a string that is inappropriate for the `time()` function.  Please edit your question to show sample data.  A SQL Fiddle is helpful too.

Comment: See as below comment

Comment: Please post the results of running this query directly. The raw SQL response from MySQL or PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: i have posted above, i believe Polymer must be sorting as the id's are keys on the returned data. Not sure how to post back un named objects from the query results.

Comment: OK, well it seems Polymer 'dom-repeat' is auto sorting my data based on the id that was the key to each result.

I simply changed the output on on my query results to be key'd with the 'starttime' and they are being sorted by that exactly how i want it.

This seems odd and not very well documented on the polymer page.

Gosh what a waste of several hours.. Thanks everyone for your help. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Note that [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time):

> Extracts the time part of the time or datetime expression expr and returns it as a string.

Which means `ORDER BY TIME(property_card_bookings_starttime)` orders by strings which is not what you want.

Provided these columns are `DATETIME` formats, you can order them directly:

```
ORDER BY property_card_bookings_starttime
```

Comment: starttime  is a 'datetime' example of data '2015-09-07 16:00:00'

Comment: You'd think this would work... except for the weird order that is shown in the image above, which does not correspond to a sequencing by strings.

Comment: i get the same results with just ORDER BY

Comment: @ChrisLear, indeed. There is likely something else going on here. But this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: I suspect it's actually a red herring. The problem is probably something else altogether, hence "nothing i try seems to work"

Comment: @22Ryann can you update the question to include the raw query output instead? Something else is effecting your ordering.

Comment: All my $ajax calls using javascript work fine, i only seem to be having issues with this iron-ajax call. :/

Comment: My assumption is that the problem does not lie in MySQL as the query I provided above *should* work. Something else is reordering your results. Please post the raw SQL results, not the AJAX response.

Comment: OK, well it seems Polymer 'dom-repeat' is auto sorting my data based on the id that was the key to each result.

I simply changed the output on on my query results to be key'd with the 'starttime' and they are being sorted by that exactly how i want it.

This seems odd and not very well documented on the polymer page.

Gosh what a waste of several hours.. Thanks everyone for your help. Very much appreciated

Comment: Regardless, you should not sort by `TIME()`.